# Clonezilla imaging/restoring from the network

Tags: samba

I am new to the imaging world so please forgive me.

I understand the basic concept of creating/restoring an image off an external hard drive on a computer.

The problem I am running into is I can't point or map the connection from a Windows shared folder where I have the image saved on. So I can restore drop the image on machines from the network instead of my external drive. I am running Clonezilla - live - 2.6.7-28-i686.

From some tutorials I have been watching they suggest to use the Samba server option when setting up the restore over the network, then I select DHCP, then they ask IP address of the server. The share we have the image saved on I am attaching the path to it. I put in the IP address of that share `\\sseldc1` which is `10.11.18.22`. Then the next screen asks for the domain, I leave it blank. Asks for my admin account and password. I get this error mounting error which I will attach as well. Any ideas what I am doing wrong?

[image]

Comment: I clone and restore to a samba server all the time so I'm quite familiar with the process. But I can't figure out from your very verbose problem description exactly what you are doing wrong. I suggest you edit your question to include each of the Clonezilla questions about networking and your answers. Not as screen shots, but type them in.  *The error you are getting suggests you are supplying the wrong directory*

Comment: Please refer https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic, Ubuntu and official flavors of Ubuntu (https://ubuntu.com/download/flavours) are on-topic on this site. The on-topic link provides alternate SE sites for non-Ubuntu OSes. *I see no link to anything on-topic for this site, no OS is mentioned so why ask here?*